# Apply h:outputScript target="body" to every included JavaScript file

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Is it possible to apply `h:outputScript target="body"` to every JavaScript file that is included without specifying them one by one? For example when using PrimeFaces client side validation `beanvalidation.js` is added inside page `<head>` tag, and I would like to have it before `</body>` tag.